# How to keep a List unfragmented (read explanation)

Tags: java, android, algorithm, optimization

I have the following problem (simplified for te example)

I have **items** identified by its ids

```
class Item {
   private int id;
   public int getId(){
      return id;
   }
}
```

And I want to keep them in a class (lets name it **ItemGroup**) with the following conditions:

- `ItemGroup.getItems()`   should return an `List<Item>` (is not necessary the list to be ordered by item id)
- Everytime I add a new item to the `ItemGroup` it should only maintain the items with the higher and **consecutive** ids. Some examples to explain it better:

  - Existing items= [5,6], itemsToAdd=[7,8], result=[5,6,7,8]
  - Existing items= [5,6], itemsToAdd=[8,9], result=[8,9]
  - Existing items= [5,6], itemsToAdd=[3,4], result=[3,4,5,6]
  - Existing items= [5,6], itemsToAdd=[1,2], result=[5,6]

The target is to implement a chat where the messages are recovered from the server in small packets and the main requirement is the thread to have the last messages without having a fragmented thread (with missing messages).

The main problem appears when the client is, for example, in the version 5 and the server is in the version 1000. The client recover the last 10 messages finding the items with ids (90-100]. In that case I want to discard the old messages, allowing the user to scroll up, recovering previous messages if needed.

How can I implement this efficiently? The options i've considered are:

1. Use a `List<Items>`, running a Collections.sort() everytime a new item (or group of items) is added. Then iterate the list decreasingly and when I detect a jump in the ids discard the remaining items.
2. Use a TreeSet, defragmenting the list the same way after the set is modified. The method `getItems()` returning an `new ArrayList<Item>(treeSet)`
3. Use a `List`, everytime a item need to ve inserted, look the correct position with a binary search, insert the item there and then defragment the list. Return the unmodified list in the `getItems()` method
4. More solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Can added items and existing items intersect (i.e. adding [2,3] to [3,4])?

Comment: No, items are unique =). Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your IDs are unique, from the examples I assume they are. I also assume both inserted and main lists have consequential elements initially
If so, algorithm would be simple:

1. Sort both your lists before inserting
2. Compare the lowest (first) element in inserted list and the highest (last) in main list, if they differ by 1 - insert into end, if they differ by more - replace main list, return
3. Compare the highest element in inserted list and the lowest in main list, if they differ by 1 - insert into beginning, if they differ by more than 1 - discard inserted list.

This algorighm has best-case performance of O(n) (O(1) for values comparison, O(n) for elements insertion), which will be always achieved provided noone messes with the lists and they are always sorted.